# all possible combination of a list within a range

Tags: python

I have this list:

input : `[1,7,8,9,10,11,19]`

I'm looking for this output:

ouput: `[[1],[7],[7,8],[7,8,9],[7,8,9,10],[7,8,9,10,11],[8,9,10,11],[9,10,11],[10,11],[11] [19]]`

in the output, I have all groups that are in a 5 digit range. `1` is in `(1,2,3,4,5)`, there's nothing in `(2,3,4,5,6)`, then 7 is in `(3,4,5,6,7)` and so on...

I've tried this program, but it doesn't give me the result i'm looking for

```
playersHand = []

table = [1,7,8,9,10,11,19]
for n in range(len(table)):
    playersHand.append(int(table[n]))
 
playersHand.sort()

cardsSet = set(playersHand)

possibleStraight = []
possibleStraightgrade = []
possibleStraightgradelist = []


for f in cardsSet:
    possibleStraightset = cardsSet.intersection(range(f,f+5))
    possibleStraightlist = list(possibleStraightset)
    possibleStraightlist.sort()
    possibleStraight.append(possibleStraightlist)
    
for n in possibleStraight:
        if n != 0:
            possibleStraightgrade = max(n)
            possibleStraightgradelist.append(possibleStraightgrade)

print(possibleStraight)
```

which gives me this:

```
[[1], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [8, 9, 10, 11], [9, 10, 11], [10, 11], [11], [19]]
```

Comment: What precisely is your question?

Comment: If you're trying to print all consecutive progressions, then you're missing things like `[8, 9, 10]`, as well as several singletons, in your expected output.

Comment: For every combination you could just do `[list(itertools.combinations(a, x)) for x in range(1,5)]` - but I suspect you want something more complex in what lists are output?

Comment: You might want to look into the builtin library ` itertools`. there's some functions you could use

Comment: What is the logic? Why is `[1, 7]` missing for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a = [1,7,8,9,10,11,19]

# get all tuples
out = [t for i in range(max(a)) if (t:=tuple(x for x in a if x in range(i, i+5)))]
# remove possible duplicates while preserving order
out = list(dict.fromkeys(out))
```

It gives:

```
[(1,),
 (7,),
 (7, 8),
 (7, 8, 9),
 (7, 8, 9, 10),
 (7, 8, 9, 10, 11),
 (8, 9, 10, 11),
 (9, 10, 11),
 (10, 11),
 (11,),
 (19,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the result more directly using a list comprehension and set intersections with potential series of 5:

```
L = [1,7,8,9,10,11,19]
S = [ sorted(s)
      for f in range(min(L),max(L)-3)                    # potential series
      for s in [set(range(f,f+5)).intersection(L)] if s] # intersection

print(S)
[[1], [7], [7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 
 [8, 9, 10, 11], [9, 10, 11], [10, 11], [11], [19]]
```

Comment: this is the result i'm looking for, but why do you put -3 in max(L)-3? I understand that it is to remove the last 3 [19], but shouldn't there be 5 [19] at the end since range(f,f+5)? Because if the L = [1,7,8,9,10,11,19,20,21], i should have has a result [[1], [7], [7, 8], [7, 8, 9], ... , [10, 11], [11], [19], [19, 20], [19, 20, 21],[19,20,21],[19,20,21],[20,21],[21]], but with instead i get [ ... [11], [19], [19, 20], [19, 20, 21]] with max(L)-3 and i get [...[11], [19], [19, 20], [19, 20, 21], [19, 20, 21], [19, 20, 21], [20, 21]]with max(L) only and it's missing the last [21]????

Comment: The expected output started the first sequence at 1 and the last one at 19 so I assumed that the minimum and maximum values in the list were the bounds of the series (i.e. from [1...5] to [15...19]).  If it can go up to 21, independently of the list's content, then use `for f in range(1,18)` instead of `for f in range(min(L),max(L)-3)`,   If it can go beyond (or even before) the value range, you can add/subtract the appropriate values from the range.

Comment: yeah but if you take the first list L = [1,7,8,9,10,11,19], you're going to have 5 x [19] at the end. Is there any way to get rid of them?